# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ '$in': [ new ObjectId("6359f421fd4678e2eba3ffee") ] }" (type Object) at path "author" for model "Blog"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a blog model:

```
let blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
title: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
description: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
content: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
likes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
views: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true },
tags: [],
currentState: { type: String, enum: ['draft', 'published'], required: true, default: 'draft' }}, { timestamps: true });
```

and a user model which I don't think is necessary to show.

When I try querying for a blog with the author matching a list of userids that the current user is following as such:
`let blogs = await Blog.find({ author: { $in: blogIds } })`
It gives me the error: **CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ '$in': [ new ObjectId("6359f421fd4678e2eba3ffee") ] }" (type Object) at path "author" for model "Blog"**

How do I get the blogs? I've tried using the $or operator but I would have to loop and it doesn't work anyway. The array values in `$in` is found correctly as shown in the error, it isn't converting properly though.

**The blogids array is [ new ObjectId("6359f421fd4678e2eba3ffee") ]. It is dynamic and is an array of userids that the user follows (OOPS, the name isn't clear)**

Comment: Can you paste your blogIds array?

Comment: If you query for a single `author`, does it work?

Comment: I don't use `mongoose`, but it seems that sometimes it casts, and sometimes it doesn't.  Perhaps try with an array of just strings (because `mongoose` may cast them to `ObjectId`s), or maybe with an array of `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(...)` where you cast each string yourself.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I am not sure how to do so as I am taking an already cast ObjectId

Comment: I don't know `mongoose` ... is `ObjectId` exactly the same as `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`?

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be problem in your blogIds array.Try to convert all value inside it with mongoose.Types.ObjectId.

```
const allIds=blogIds.map(item=>mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item));
```

Then update your find query.

```
const blogs = await Blog.find({ author: { $in: allIds } });
```

Comment: This isn't working; it gives me: **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
  '$in': [
    new ObjectId("6359f421fd4678e2eba3ffee"),
    new ObjectId("636885521e3a13fad266556f")
  ]
}" (type Object) at path "author" for model "Blog"**

Comment: its alright I fixed it using a hack without `$in` and I'm not sure why it works. I'm going to delete this question since it wasn't asked really well.

Comment: may be problem with new keyword because it's a constructor in js . so if your array is like  [ObjectId("6359f421fd4678e2eba3ffee") ...] then it should work.

Comment: i couldn't figure out how to remove the new :(

Comment: Are you getting blogIds from frontend?

Comment: no its in the backend stored in the database